# Initialize firebase config based on environment

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Right now in my project, I have 2 separate firebase config files for test and prod environment. When the app is being built/deployed, jenkins is going to initialize firebase with the appropriate configs.

Now I want to add cloud messaging from firebase and I want to handle the messages inside my single page react app. How can I have access to the initialized firebase instance in my react code (i.e. App.jsx)?

_library/firebase.config.prod.js

```
// Firebase (production)

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAX...tXE8ZSM",
  authDomain: "aaa.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://aaa.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "aaa",
  storageBucket: "aaa.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "4246...326",
  appId: "1:4245971.....c50fc5bac008",
  measurementId: "G-XQ...PTBF"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
```

_library/firebase.config.test.js

```
// Firebase (default)

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAq58Q_Q....8GV6Vs8zAa2DM",
  authDomain: "aaa-test.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://aaa-test.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "aaa-test",
  storageBucket: "aaa-test.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "9160....111",
  appId: "1:9160372441.....b70e3859d93ba",
  measurementId: "G-4X....BV64"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
```

Comment: Make it a global or singleton?

Comment: @DougStevenson How and where should I initialize the firebase instance?

Comment: I think that's a matter of opinion. Have you tried anything yet?  Have you searched for existing conventions?

Comment: I updated my question with the current implementation. But I'm unable to call `firebase.messaging()` (for example) in my react code (App.jsx)

Comment: Have you tried saving the instance of firebase to a variable then exporting that variable to import and use in components or similar? Have you had a chance to search for tutorials react + firebase? Other than loading config based on environment almost all of them show effectively the same strategy to initialize and expose firebase to react components/store/context.